# Is any way I can make a container template with template?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <class ContainerType, class elementType>
void SerializeContainer (    ContainerType< elementType > container )
{
}

//call like this 
std::vector<int>  vector;
SerializeContainer(vector);
```

below will not compile.. Is there any way I can get through this?

Comment: _How_ doesn't it compile? Can you please edit your question to include the errors (complete an unedited please).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easier to use the `value_type` member of the container to extract the element type:

```
  template <typename T>
  void SerializeContainer (const T& container)
  {
      typedef typename T::value_type ElementType;
      ..........
  }
```

---

The reason why your code does not work is because the syntax `ContainerType<ElementType>` only works when `ContainerType` is a really template. C++ support the template-template parameter for this:

```
template <template <typename> class ContainerType, typename ElementType>
void serializeContainer(const ContainerType<ElementType>& container) {
}
```

But even this will *not*  match for standard C++ containers, because there are some hidden default arguments. When written explicitly:

```
std::vector<int, 
            std::allocate<int> >   vector;
```

So you'll need to make the ContainerType parameter to accept 2 arguments:

```
template <typename <typename, typename> C, typename E, typename A>
void serializeContainer(const C<E, A>& container) {
}
```

But then this won't match `set::set` because it has a different number of template parameters:

```
std::set<int, 
         std::less<int>, 
         std::allocator<int> >  set;
```

There simply isn't a one-size-fit-all solution (before C++11) if you want the ElementType spelled explicitly when matching. It's better to stick with the traits provided by the container.